# How to improve execution speed on large data sort in C

Tags: c, performance, sorting, insertion-sort

I managed to roll off an insertion sort routine as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int n;
    char l;
    char z;
} dat;

void sortx(dat* y){
    char tmp[sizeof(dat)+1];
    dat *sp=y;
    while(y->l){
        dat *ip=y;
        while(ip>sp && ip->n < (ip-1)->n){
            memcpy(tmp,ip,sizeof(dat));
            memcpy(ip,ip-1,sizeof(dat));
            memcpy(ip-1,tmp,sizeof(dat));
            ip--;
        }
        y++;
    }
}

void printa(dat* y){
    while(y->l){printf("%c %d,",y->l,y->n);y++;}
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    const long sz=10000;
    dat* new=calloc(sz+2,sizeof(dat));
    dat* randx=new;
    //fill struct array with random values
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < sz ; i++) {
        randx->l = (unsigned char)(65+(rand() % 25));
        randx->n = (rand() % 1000);randx++;
    }
    //sort - takes forever
    sortx(new);
    printa(new);
    free(new);
    return 0;
}
```

My sorting routine was partly derived from:  http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-insertion-sort
but because I am dealing with sorting the array based on the numeric value in the struct, memcpy works for me so far.

The computer I'm using to execute this code has a Pentium 1.6Ghz Processor and when I change sz in the main function to at least 20000, I notice I have to wait two seconds to see the results on the screen.

The reason why I'm testing large numbers is because I want to process server logs in C and will be sorting information by timestamps and sometimes the logs can become very large, and I don't want to put too much strain on the CPU as it is running other processes already such as apache.

Is there anyway I can improve this code so I don't have to wait two seconds to see 20000 structs sorted?

Comment: *Is there anyway I can improve this code so I don't have to wait two seconds to see 20000 structs sorted?* Don't use insertion sort? It is an inefficient sorting algorithm.

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort? **It's 2015**, use a library function.

Comment: Because I need to write something for the core of the server. If I start adding libraries and the code within those libraries execute extra unnecessary functionality then it will make my program slower

Comment: The modern linkers are smart enough to link only the needed functions (in case of static linkage, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a function that does this, and it's built in in the C standard library: [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). You just have to provide suitable comparison function.

This function has to return `-1` if the item taken as a left argument should be put earlier in the desired order, `1` if it should be put later, *or* `0` if the items are to be considered equal by `qsort`.

```
int dat_sorter(const void* l, const void* r)
{
    const dat* left = (const dat*)l;
    const dat* right = (const dat*)r;
    if(left->n > right->n)
        return 1;
    else if(left->n < right->n)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void sortx(dat* y)
{
    /* find the length */
    dat* it = y;
    size_t count = 0;
    while(it->l)
    {
        count++;
        it++;
    }
    /* do the sorting */
    qsort(y, count, sizeof(dat), dat_sorter);
}
```

If you want to speed it up even more, you can make `sortx` function take length of the array, so the function won't need to figure it out on its own.

Comment: now that qsort function is well defined for me, at least for now. I just have to figure out whether it would be reliable in the long run in comparison to other sorting techniques.

Comment: `qsort` is as reliable and generalized as you can practically get as a standard C function that has more wide testing and exposure and turning than probably any other sorting algorithm implemented for C. Since it only requires a comparator, it also works for practically anything (numeric keys, string keys, `struct Foo` keys, etc). To do better, you often have to sacrificing generality or rely on code generation to generate code that only sorts one specific data type (ex: C++'s `std::sort` which does that with templates or `tbb:sort` which does it with both templates and multithreading).

Comment: You can get better performance by sacrificing generality and coming up with a sort that only works in specific scenarios, like a radix sort, but if you're looking for your daily bread and butter sorting routine that works for anything in C, `qsort` is it.

Answer (score 0):

Use quick sort, heap sort, or bottom up merge sort. Wiki has examples of these in their articles, and typically have more complete examples on each article's talk page.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort has O(n^2) time complexity, and there are other algorithms out there that will give you O(nlogn) time complexity like mergesort, quicksort, and heapsort. It looks like you are sorting by an integer, so you also might want to consider using LSD radix sort, which is O(n) time complexity.